# Key error in serializers while using .values() in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, aggregation

I want to filter and count the tasks based on their status. Additionally, I also want to add a count of tasks that are due in this week. I tried using .annotate() and .values(), but I am facing key error. Here is my code, as well as the error.

[image]

Here is my code:
models.py:

```
class TaskStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.status)

class Task_category(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job,related_name='Job',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    assigner = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='assigner', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='assignee', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit,related_name='UnitName',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment,related_name='EquipmentName',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date =  models.DateField()   
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(TaskStatus, related_name='Status',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)
```

serializers.py:

```
class TaskcategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task_category
        fields = ['id','job','name','category','start_date','end_date','created_at','updated_at','status','assignee', 'unit', 'equipment', 'assigner']
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(TaskcategorySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['job'] = instance.job.name
        rep['unit'] = instance.unit.name
        rep['equipment'] = instance.equipment.name
        rep['status'] = instance.status.status
        return rep
```

views.py:

```
class ChartView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    queryset = Task_category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskcategorySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task_category.objects.annotate(value=Count('status')).values('status__status')
```

Please help. Any sort of help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

**`.values()`** and then **`.annotate()`** gives you the functionality of grouping

```
class ChartView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    queryset = Task_category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskcategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task_category.objects.values('status__status').annotate(value=Count('status__status')
```

Comment: Also, I tried using values before annotate, still it showed me the same error as above

Comment: Yeah, because you have already a field named `status`

Comment: Doing this doesnt give me the count of tasks according to their status

Comment: @GautamShah you need group_by functionality?

Comment: I didnt find the group_by functionality in django docs. But yes, I want to get a count of tasks based on their status i.e complete, overdue etc.

Comment: first `values` then `annotate` gives you the `group by` functionality

Comment: Also, apart from just having the tasks based on their status, I also want to get the number of tasks that are due in this week. It has something to do with the end_date and the date.today(), but couldnt not figure out how to do it

Comment: Okay so yes I want the group_by functionality

Comment: about `due` date,, you could make use of the `Case When`, conditional aggregation, doc here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation

Comment: Will have a look. Thank you so much!